# classless network

Tags: ipv4

I'm having trouble figuring setup for my network, have done quite some reading and testing already, yet still, some solutions remain unclear to me and I hope to find an answer for these here.

What I need to achieve is **setup a classless configuration for a private, C-type network of a minimum of 15 sub-networks**.

As far as I have read, a **class network** with sub-networks has fixed mask, which remains the same for each an every sub-network, making the whole setup inefficient. A classless network has a variable mask, allowing IP address to be divided into hosts and network parts according to current requirements. Having that in mind I'm doing the following calculations which were described as classless IP assignment:

IP: 192.168.1.0/24
2^4=4 networks available (2 bits taken from the hosts part)
2^6-2=62 hosts in each max (6 bits left)
New mask: 26 => 255.255.255.192

```
1st network
Subnet: 192.168.1.0
First address: 192.168.1.1
Last address: 192.168.1.62
Broadcast: 192.168.1.63

2nd network
Subnet: 192.168.1.64
First address: 192.168.1.65
Last address: 192.168.1.126
Broadcast: 192.168.1.127

    etc
```

How is the above different from regular sub-networks division? It seems to be the same as the mask does not change. Is VLSM a way to go here? What is the real difference between class and classless network? How should the proper setup look like?

Comment: Welcom to the NE Stack Exchange. Could you tell us your real-world configuration? What network size do you have to start with (or can you choose freely)? How many subnets do you need  and why (different security zones, different departments, ...)? Right now this sounds a bit like a homework question and these are off-topic here.

Comment: It is an assignment indeed, yet I did not find better place to ask for suggestions so I did some research and have exact task to solve at this point

Comment: Unfortunately, school assignments and homework are off-topic here.

Comment: I strongly disagree, question can be raised at anytime, no matter where it originates from. I'm not asking for a precise answer but rather for an explanation of the difference between concept of class and classless networks. Does it make that much of a difference if one wants to learn while doing school assignment, work project or own start-up development?

Comment: @jacek_podwysocki, homework questions are a bit tricky. On one hand, we are not here to do homework for students who don't want to do the work themselves and we do not want to encourage that behavior. On the other hand, original questions raised about networking based on homework could make a good question and we would like to encourage that behavior. However sometimes it is difficult to make the distinction between the two and it is our policy in those cases to treat it like they are homework questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How is the above different from regular sub-networks division?

Well, Classless Inter-Domain Routing (CIDR) is about reclaiming unused address space.  Take a classful Class A network for instance - 1.0.0.0/8.  Below is from an IP Address calculator on Linux:

```
Address:   1.0.0.0              00000001. 00000000.00000000.00000000
Netmask:   255.0.0.0 = 8        11111111. 00000000.00000000.00000000
Wildcard:  0.255.255.255        00000000. 11111111.11111111.11111111
=>
Network:   1.0.0.0/8            00000001. 00000000.00000000.00000000
HostMin:   1.0.0.1              00000001. 00000000.00000000.00000001
HostMax:   1.255.255.254        00000001. 11111111.11111111.11111110
Broadcast: 1.255.255.255        00000001. 11111111.11111111.11111111
Hosts/Net: 16777214              Class A
```

Look at the output above, you can see that this customer has at their disposal >16 million IP Addresses - it's just ridiculously ludicrous!

So, ARIN (American Registry of Internet Numbers) can walk up to this customer and tell them, look here, you only have 20 employees - do you really need over 16 million IP Address (or 838,860 IP Addresses per employee)?

ARIN can then reduce this customers waste and make it available to others needing it more and cuts down this customers' Network from a classful Class A network to a classless network of 1.0.0.0/24:

```
Address:   1.0.0.0              00000001.00000000.00000000. 00000000
Netmask:   255.255.255.0 = 24   11111111.11111111.11111111. 00000000
Wildcard:  0.0.0.255            00000000.00000000.00000000. 11111111
=>
Network:   1.0.0.0/24           00000001.00000000.00000000. 00000000
HostMin:   1.0.0.1              00000001.00000000.00000000. 00000001
HostMax:   1.0.0.254            00000001.00000000.00000000. 11111110
Broadcast: 1.0.0.255            00000001.00000000.00000000. 11111111
Hosts/Net: 254                   Class A
```

Please note that although the designation is still a Class A network (this is solely inferred by the fact that the 1st bit (from the left - aka the most significant bit) is a 0), the IP Address usage has been reduced significantly - from 16,777,214 IP Address per network, to just 254!

Just remember though, that having too many networks just for the sake of it could also be wasteful as you lose 2 IP Address for every network!

Comment: Thanks, that explained the topic. Do I got it right that VLSM technique for distributing networks of unequal number of hosts is same as networks division using classless model?

Comment: If you grasp CIDR, then VLSM is quite frankly the same - efficiently using your publicly allocated IP network.  For instance, when joining 2 offices, you should use a /30 mask which gives you 2 useable IP Addresses.  But the key thing is avoiding overlap!  You have to plan your network properly.  Larger subnets (ones with more hosts) need to appear first then smaller ones at the end.  See https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/thread/65627.  I hope that answers your question fully.